# Stored Procedure returning data off by one column - sql 2012

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am running this stored Procedure in sql 2012  the date range at the time is 2014-01-01 to 2014-02-01. and I am doing a rolling sum for all 31 days in January 2014.  The SP is summing correctly but my result set is off by one day.  It is not returning 1-1-2014 and is returning 2-1-2014.  Are applying a fulltime stamp to each recorded so I am doing a between.  This logic works in some SP just fine and in others it is off.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
USE [Reports]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_rpt_KPI_Channel_Daily_Actual_January14]    Script Date: 2/21/2014 8:51:04 AM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_rpt_KPI_Channel_Daily_Actual_January14]
    @channel varchar(50) --This designed to use either:  Enterprise Account, House Account, Inside Sales Account, Major Account
                         --                              National Account or Retail Record Type
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @StartDate Date = Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -50, getdate()), 110)
    DECLARE @Today Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE()-19, 101) -- Today

--DECLARE @channel varchar(50);

DECLARE @local_channel varchar(50);
SET @local_channel = @channel;
--SET @channel = 'Enterprise Account'

  SELECT   

    c.Account_RecordType

    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -50, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -49, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/01/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -49, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -48, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/02/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -48, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -47, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/03/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -47, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -46, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/04/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -46, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -45, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/05/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -45, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -44, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/06/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -44, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -43, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/07/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -43, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -42, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/08/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -42, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -41, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/09/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -41, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -40, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/10/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -40, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -39, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/11/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -39, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -38, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/12/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -38, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -37, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/13/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -37, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -36, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/14/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -36, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -35, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/15/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -35, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -34, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/16/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -34, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -33, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/17/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -33, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -32, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/18/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -32, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -31, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/19/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -31, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -30, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/20/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -30, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -29, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/21/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -29, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -28, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/22/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -28, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -27, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/23/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -27, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -26, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/24/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -26, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -25, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/25/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -25, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -24, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/26/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -24, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -23, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/27/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -23, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -22, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/28/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -22, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -21, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/29/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -21, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -20, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/30/2014'
    ,Sum(case when a.timewait between DateAdd(d, -20, CONVERT (date, getdate())) and DateAdd(d, -19, CONVERT (date,getdate())) then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as '01/31/2014'


FROM  SalesForce.dbo.SalesForceContact AS b INNER JOIN
      Dossier_Replication.dbo.vwSF_DATA_Contact c ON b.ContactID = c.CONTACTID__C RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory AS a ON b.UserID = a.UserID_Caller

WHERE (b.Platform = 'HandsonVRS') AND (a.timeWait BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Today) 
                                  AND (a.isReport = '1') 
                                  AND (a.NECA_isReport = '1') 
                                  AND (a.ConvoTime > '0')
                                  AND (c.Account_RecordType = @channel)

GROUP BY 
        c.Account_RecordType
END
```

Answer (score 0):

@Y    @StartDate Date = Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, -50, getdate()), 110)

evaluates to Jan 2, 2014 on Feb 21, 2014 (when your question was posted.)  @Today evaluates to Feb 2 using your formula.  I think you just need to adjust your offsets.